# Safari on iOS16.4 creates a serviceWorker without PushManager. Why?

Tags: ios, safari, progressive-web-apps, web-push

My PWA has web-push working with Safari on MacOS (and Chrome and Firefox), but on Safari on iOS 16.4 the ServiceWorkerRegistration object does not contain PushManager:

```
ServiceWorkerRegistration: {
  listeners: {updatefound: Array}
  active: ServiceWorker {scriptURL: "http://localhost:9200/sw.js", state: "activated",   onstatechange: null, onerror: null, postMessage: function, …}
  installing: null
  navigationPreload: NavigationPreloadManager {enable: function, disable: function, setHeaderValue:   function, getState: function}
  onupdatefound: function()
  scope: "http://localhost:9200/"
  updateViaCache: "imports"
  waiting: null
}
```

I know 16.4 is supposed to support the web-push standard now, so what am I missing?

I've checked that it is not just an issue with the xcode iPhone emulator, I get the same failure on an actual iPhone. I don't know what else to try because it seems like a browser issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I was running the PWA in the Safari browser on iOS, which Apple intentionally doesn't support (which is different from Chrome and Firefox). What *is* supported per [the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending_web_push_notifications_in_web_apps_safari_and_other_browsers) is "Home Screen web apps in iOS 16.4 or later", which is to say, downloading the PWA to the iPhone home screen and opening it from there. Once I ran the standalone PWA, the ServiceWorkerRegistration included the PushManager.

Side note, web-push notifications still didn't work in the xcode simulator, because they aren't currently supported. When I tried, the app would request permissions and just be stuck there. However, once I tested the same app on an actual iPhone (and downloaded the PWA to the home screen), push notifications were fully functioning!

Comment: Thanks a lot.. i was trying to get it work on simulator, 2 days and nothing...