# Firebase Notification IOS 16.4 PWA onMessage is not triggered

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

works fine on all systems, but in pwa ios 16.4 onMessage does not trigger when receiving a push although it works correctly in other browsers. That's why I can't get the push data

Maybe someone knows what can be the problem?

Comment: Possibility [the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76222241/safari-on-ios16-4-creates-a-serviceworker-without-pushmanager-why)

Comment: no, push notifications come correctly, but I can't get data from push via onMessage subscription. The method not called

Comment: Maybe the service worker is not active, so even the push is fired, the ```onMessage``` will not be triggered.